# Remove specific number of characters in csv

Tags: python, sql, csv

I have some CSV files being exported from an SQL database and transferred to me daily for me to import into my SQL server. The files all have a "title" line in them with 27 characters, the business name and date. I.e. "busname: 08-31-2020". I need a script that can remove those first 27 characters so they aren't imported into the database.

Is this possible? I can't find anything that will let me select a specific number of characters at the beginning of the file.

Comment: If you are using read or have access to the file data as a Python str, you can just: ```data[27:]```

Comment: This "title" is the first line in the file, or it prefixes every line?

Comment: This is the first line of the csv, depending on the application used to open it, it is either the first cell (A1) or the first 27 characters of line 1.

pointuniversity: 09-01-2020
Session ID,Session Title,Action User,Action Type,Action Time

Answer (score 0):

If you value is in the column 1 you can use `str[27:]` to get all the str after the given value.

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        process_str = row[1][27:]
```

You can after create a new file using this processed string